# Json within a Json

Tags: json, gson

I am using gson for serializing and deserializing.  I have the following Object:

```
OBJECT A:
String myEmail;
int    rank;
String msgData;
```

In the above case, msgData is a json String, so the above object in json form would be deserialized in 2 steps.  For particular reasons, we have to do this in 2 steps.  Object B below - will be the json for msgData above.

```
OBJECT B:
String myName;
int myNumber;
String[] myStrings;
```

The Json for Object B is the following:

```
{
  "myName": "TheJumper",
  "myNumber": "35",
  "myString": [
    "abc",
    "efg",
    "xyz"
  ]
}
```

The Question:  How do we represent json - OBJECT B; in the json form for OBJECT A, so that when OBJECT A is deserialized, the json for OBJECT B can be extracted as a String.

For Example:  The Json for Object A can be represented as (Valid Json):

```
{
  "myEmail": "abc@example.com",
  "myRank": "50",
  "msgData": "This is a Message"
}
```

When I try the following - it give me an error of invalid json.

```
{
  "myEmail": "abc@example.com",
  "myRank":  "50",
  "msgData": "{
      "myName": "TheJumper",
      "myNumber": "35",
      "myString": [
        "abc",
        "efg",
        "xyz"
      ]
    }"
}
```

I have tried a number of things but could not resolve it.   How would this be done?

Comment: quotes need to be escaped. "{ \"name\" : \"foo\"}"

Comment: Thanks Claude Martin.   I had tried the above suggestion - but left Object B in multiple lines.   I checked with JsonLint and it had given me an error.   It seems that if Object B is represented in a single line with escape then it works.  Any reason why? (see nickb answer reply).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do we represent json - OBJECT B; in the json form for OBJECT A, so that when OBJECT A is deserialized, the json for OBJECT B can be extracted as a String.

You would need to escape all of the quotes with `\"` in the OBJECT B JSON string;

```
{
  "myEmail": "abc@example.com",
  "myRank":  "50",
  "msgData": "{
      \"myName\": \"TheJumper\",
      \"myNumber\": \"35\",
      \"myString\": [
        \"abc\",
        \"efg\",
        \"xyz\"
      ]
    }"
}
```

Collapsed on a single line, it looks like:

```
{
    "myEmail": "abc@example.com",
    "myRank": "50",
    "msgData": "{ \"myName\": \"TheJumper\", \"myNumber\": \"35\", \"myString\": [ \"abc\", \"efg\", \"xyz\" ] }"
}
```

However, a better approach is writing valid JSON, and then converting its representation to a string. This way, you don't need to worry about escaping anything. For example, you would have:

```
{
  "myEmail": "abc@example.com",
  "myRank":  "50",
  "msgData": {
      "myName": "TheJumper",
      "myNumber": "35",
      "myString": [
        "abc",
        "efg",
        "xyz"
      ]
    }
}
```

Then, when you get to `msgData`, use GSON to convert it to a String with [`Gson#toJson()`](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#toJson(com.google.gson.JsonElement))

Comment: Thanks nickb.  I had tried the same as your first code.   The first code - when checked on jsonlint gives an error.   But when I checked your second code - "single line" -- that was validated.   Any reason why the first code was not considered valid.